# How do I set the weighed in linear regression model in R?

Tags: r

I have the following data in R and I want to get the linear regression model for `y~x1+x2+x3+x4` using weighted least square. If I want to use the sample variance as the basis for weighted squares estimation of the original data.

Schubert et al. (1992) conducted an experiment with a catapult to determine
the effects of hook (
x
1
), arm length (
x
2
), start angle (
x
3
), and stop angle (
x
4
) on the
distance (
y
) that the catapult throws a ball. They throw the ball three times for each
setting of the factors. The following table summarizes the experimental results, where
the factor levels of
x
1
, x
2
, x
3
and
x
4
are standardized

```
x1<-c(-1,-1,-1,-1,1,1,1,1)
x2<-c(-1,-1,1,1,-1,-1,1,1)
x3<-c(-1,1,-1,1,-1,1,-1,1)
x4<-c(-1,1,1,-1,1,-1,-1,1)
y<-c(28,46.3,21.9,52.9,75,127.7,86.2,195)
```

How do I write this code in R? I tried the following one but I do not know how to set the weighted `w`in R. This code dose not work.

```
l=lm(y~x1+x2+x3+x4, weights=1/x)
```

Comment: This is not clear to me. What do these predictor values `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` denote? Is this some manual dummy encoding of categorical variable(s)? Why do they only take values `-1` and `1`? You state that you want to use "sample variance as the basis for weighted squares estimation". The variance of what exactly?

Comment: Perhaps [this is what you're after](https://www.statology.org/weighted-least-squares-in-r/)?

Comment: @MauritsEvers Yes, but the example you post is just about `y~x`. But how to set `y~x1+x2+x3+x4`? There would be error for the weight.

Comment: @MauritsEvers The sample variance as the basis for weighted squares estimation of the original data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothwithstanding the lack of clarifications and details around your model and data (see below), I think you're after something like this:

```r
# Store sample data in `data.frame`
df <- data.frame(y, x1, x2, x3, x4)

# First: "Vanilla" OLS estimation
fit_OLS <- lm(y ~ ., data = df)

# Second: Weights
weights <- 1 / fitted(lm(abs(residuals(fit_OLS)) ~ fitted(fit_OLS))) ^ 2

# Third: Weighted least squares estimation
fit_WLS <- lm(y ~  ., data = df, weights = weights)

# Compare coefficients
coef(fit_OLS)
#(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3          x4 
#     79.125      41.850       9.875      26.350       5.425 
coef(fit_WLS)
#(Intercept)          x1          x2          x3          x4 
#     79.125      41.850       9.875      26.350       5.425
```

Not wanting to reiterate poorly what others have explained much better, I refer you to [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/246085/how-to-determine-weights-for-wls-regression-in-r), detailing the rationale behind calculating the weights.

As you can see, parameter estimates of the OLS and WLS routines are the same, since the estimated `weights` are identical.

This loops back to my original question (see comments): The values for those `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, `x4` predictors seem odd. If they denote hook, arm length, start angle and stop angle of a catapult, why do they only take on values `-1` and `1`? Did you discretise original data somehow? This is not clear but important for assessing the model fit.